# Why ajax doesn't work on certain wordpress hooks?

Tags: php, functions, ajax, hooks, nonce

I built an ajax function which works perfectly when i hook it to admin_head or admin_notices hooks but it doesn't work when i hook it to manage_posts_extra_tablenav hook, instead of doing the ajax call it just reload the page and the url of the opened page after page reload is

```
Request URL: http://localhost/wc/wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=product&_wpnonce=c1a10340ac&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwc%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fs%26post_status%3Dall%26post_type%3Dproduct%26action%3D-1%26product_cat%26product_type%26stock_status%26paged%3D1%26action2%3D-1&action=-1&product_cat=&product_type=&stock_status=&paged=1&action2=-1
```

and that upper link do a 302 redirect to that link

```
http://localhost/wc/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=product&action=-1&product_cat&product_type&stock_status&paged=1&action2=-1
```

This is my code, however both actions connected to the same function but the version on top works fine and the one on the other hook doesn't work, so i was wondering what is the reason and how to solve it?

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'apm_update_all_products_ajax' );
add_action('admin_notices', 'apm_update_all_products_ajax');

function apm_update_all_products_ajax() {
  $product_ids = wc_get_products( array( 'return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1 ) );
  ?>
    <div class="apm_bulk_update_prices_wrap alignleft actions">
  <button class="button apm_update_prices" id="update_prices" onclick="apm_update_all_products()">Update All Products</button>
    <p id="apm_bulk_status">test</p>
    </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" >
            product_ids = <?php echo json_encode($product_ids); ?>;
            product_ids_n = product_ids.length;
            product_ids_step = 0;
      function apm_update_all_products() {
                product_id = product_ids[product_ids_step];
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                                action: 'apm_update_single_product',
                                postId: product_id
                        },
                        success: function(lookup_data) {
                                product_ids_step++
                                $('#bulk_status').text('Updated ' + product_ids_step + ' of ' + product_ids_n );
                                if (product_ids_step < product_ids_n) {
                                    apm_update_all_products();
                                }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }
                    })
      };

    </script>
  <?php
}
```

and here is a screenshot showing the place of the 2 hooks
https://snag.gy/zNXUmv.jpg

My guess is that issue cause by something called nonce but i dont really understand what is nonce and how to fix it.